What does the Catholic church teach about IVF?
I met a Catholic family two years ago that utilizes in vitro fertilisation (IVF). I am inclined to believe that IVF is a completely moral practice in situations where a couple may be infertile.
I think this particular couple told me that they use IVF not because of infertility issues, but because they have a right risk of conceiving children with mental disabilities.
I don't remember the exact details, but I think they said that multiple eggs are fertilized and whichever one presents the least genetic risk of retardation is implanted in the mother's uterus. If this wasn't the case, then they may have said that another woman donates her eggs for IVF.
The first alternative sounds a lot like abortion to me, and thus would be a mortal sin. The second alternative does not seem as bad, but it still feels morally questionable.
This leaves us with three different IVF procedures:

A single egg is fertilized from the mother due to infertility.
Multiple eggs are fertilized from the mother and the "best candidate" is kept.
A different woman donates eggs for fertilization.

Even if I am misremembering the circumstances from my anecdote, I believe these to all be real IVF procedures used in the world today.
What is the Catholic Church's guidance on these procedures?

In general, the Catechism states:

2376 Techniques that entail the dissociation of husband and wife, by the intrusion of a person other than the couple (donation of sperm or ovum, surrogate uterus), are gravely immoral. These techniques (heterologous artificial insemination and fertilization) infringe the child's right to be born of a father and mother known to him and bound to each other by marriage. They betray the spouses' "right to become a father and a mother only through each other."
2377 Techniques involving only the married couple (homologous artificial insemination and fertilization) are perhaps less reprehensible, yet remain morally unacceptable. They dissociate the sexual act from the procreative act. the act which brings the child into existence is no longer an act by which two persons give themselves to one another, but one that "entrusts the life and identity of the embryo into the power of doctors and biologists and establishes the domination of technology over the origin and destiny of the human person. Such a relationship of domination is in itself contrary to the dignity and equality that must be common to parents and children." "Under the moral aspect procreation is deprived of its proper perfection when it is not willed as the fruit of the conjugal act, that is to say, of the specific act of the spouses' union .... Only respect for the link between the meanings of the conjugal act and respect for the unity of the human being make possible procreation in conformity with the dignity of the person."

So IVF is considered morally unacceptable by the Catholic Church.
And also

2270 Human life must be respected and protected absolutely from the moment of conception.

So from the moment of fertilization, the Church regards those "eggs" as human beings, as persons.
With this the answer to your questions is three nuanced different variances of "morally unacceptable"

To be honest, I was expecting the church to allow IVF in the case of infertility. Nevertheless, I like what the catechism has to say on the matter and I can see why the church does not condone it.

People expect the Church to move positions with the time, being "up to date". But in reality the Church doesn't follow the time, it follows timeless teachings :)

@CardinalSystem There are morally acceptable means that directly remedy the causes of infertility, such as NaProTECHNOLOGY. IVF is illicit means to achieve a good end (conception); ends never justify illicit means. Podcast on the topic, in light of Alabama’s recent ruling that embryos are legally children: "Catholic Teaching on IVF - Questions with Father #41 - Fr. Palko"
